# Finding an optimal schedule

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm reading through an algorithm textbook and I've come across yet another problem that I'm stuck on. I'm looking for some help solving it and if anyone could provide some similar, already-existing, problems that I could reference to follow similar steps, that'd be great.

This is the problem:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, you'll probably get a better response if you can demonstrate what you've already tried/what research you've already done to solve your own problem. (You can add info to your post by clicking "edit" in the lower-left)

Comment: No algorithm textbook problem will say "for full credit".

Answer (score 0):

Begin by trying to transform some (optimal/feasible) schedule into one (also optimal/feasible) that satisfies the criteria (a). In you starting schedule there will always be at least two jobs with their deadlines in the opposite order, i.e. the later job has the earliest deadline.  Think what happens if you exchange the places of these two jobs in the schedule.